# flutter dart-define not loading on first build, only on hot restart

Tags: flutter, environment-variables, dart-define

[image: main.dart]
[image: configuration]
[image: what i got in the first init]
[image: project.pbxproj]

Hi,
Im setting flavor for my existing app and encountered an error with String.fromEnvironment.
It only get the right flavor when I click "Hot Restart"

Im using Flutter 3.7.10
Here are my flutter doctor -v logs:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.10, on macOS 13.3.1 22E772610a darwin-arm64, locale en-VN)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
    ! Some Android licenses not accepted. To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.3.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.79.2)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
tungakanui@Tnuis-MacBook-Pro avia-flutter % fvm flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.10, on macOS 13.3.1 22E772610a darwin-arm64, locale en-VN)
    • Flutter version 3.7.10 on channel stable at /Users/tungakanui/fvm/versions/3.7.10
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 4b12645012 (3 months ago), 2023-04-03 17:46:48 -0700
    • Engine revision ec975089ac
    • Dart version 2.19.6
    • DevTools version 2.20.1

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/tungakanui/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 33.0.0
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840)
    ! Some Android licenses not accepted. To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.3.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 14E300c
    • CocoaPods version 1.12.1

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.79.2)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.64.0

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • iPhone 14 Pro (mobile) • BF0C1972-F6B0-4164-BDBF-59D6BCF6B117 • ios            • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-16-4 (simulator)
    • macOS (desktop)        • macos                                • darwin-arm64   • macOS 13.3.1 22E772610a darwin-arm64
    • Chrome (web)           • chrome                               • web-javascript • Google Chrome 114.0.5735.198

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

I want to get the right Flavor in the first init

Answer (score 1):

check file : `ios/Runner.xcodeproj/project.pdxproject` and remove all

```
buildSettings = {
   DART_DEFINES = "" // <- remove here
}
```

Comment: I can't found any line likes this in project.pbsproj

Comment: @TùngNgThanh try to find `DART_DEFINES` in the whole project. In my case I had some flavors configured and it was part of another file.

Comment: I have the issue issue after setting up flavors, but I also do not see any dart_defines in my whole project other than the ones I set in my launch.json file. Still couldn't get it to work though.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using custom .xcconfig files? If so try adding this line at the bottom of your custom .xcconfig files assuming the files are in Runner folder.

#include "../Flutter/Generated.xcconfig"